# What is the best way to hide drupal block which we have created in module

Tags: blocks

I am using GeoMap module to show maps of organizations. I am setting the data for it in the block i have defined in the custom module. I don't want to display that block (but the code in that block should be present in that page code so that GeoMap could find it and render a corresponding map.
OR is there any other better way to accomplish same

Comment: Can't you disable block from admin > structure > blocks ? Or else you are rendering it programatically ?

Comment: Yes I can disable it but then how the code inside that block will go on the page? I need to render code on the page.

Comment: Don't render it in a block?

Comment: @AlexGill where can i render the code, i want it to be render on specific nodes/pages

Comment: definitly the wrong approach for having code available .. geoMap probably let's you inject JS properties or somethiing

Comment: @rémy yes, found the way using custom fields